# WPF Designer taking a while to load

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2013

My XAML is taking quite a while to load. I have absolutely no idea why. I've tried everything, from removing the `Grid` to commenting out the whole of `MyContext` to see if it was the bindings. Nada. It just takes a while to load. It might be because I did something wrong in my XAML, though. And when I open it at runtime, it takes 1 or so seconds with no fixes, which is alright because it has to make a DB call.

Anyways, here's the offending XAML, with internal information removed:

```
<Window x:Class="MyNamespace.MyWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:lcl="clr-MyNamespace"
        Title="New User" Height="300" Width="500" ResizeMode="NoResize">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <lcl:MyContext/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="9*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="9*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Content="Data:" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <Label Content="More Data:" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3"/>
        <Label Content="Even More Data:" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="5"/>
        <Label Content="Selectable Data:" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <Grid Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="2">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button Grid.Column="1" BorderThickness="0">
                <Viewbox>
                    <Canvas Width="76" Height="76" Clip="F1 M 0,0L 76,0L 76,76L 0,76L 0,0">
                        <Path Width="38" Height="38" Canvas.Left="19" Canvas.Top="19" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FF000000" Data="F1 M 35,19L 41,19L 41,35L 57,35L 57,41L 41,41L 41,57L 35,57L 35,41L 19,41L 19,35L 35,35L 35,19 Z "/>
                    </Canvas>
                </Viewbox>
            </Button>
        </Grid>
        <ListBox Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="3" Grid.RowSpan="3" ItemsSource="{Binding MySelectableData}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, StringFormat='Name: {0}}'}"/>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding EmailAddress, StringFormat='Email Address: {0}'}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
        <Button Content="Cancel" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="7" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,0,85,0"/>
        <Button Content="OK" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="7"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```